# How to add new rows inside of *ngFor loop? I Want to Implement expanding collapsing functionality inside of the table

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want to implement expand-collapse functionality in my tables. whatever row I clicked the expanded portion should come below of that row only. I'm using angular 2. Without using any other framework how can I do so? I have tried out like below code snippet but whatever be is the row I clicked the new row (Expanded portion) always coming below of all the rows.

Here is the dummy code snippet:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>column header1</td>
    <td>column header2</td>
    <td>column header3</td>
    <td>column header4</td>
    <td></td>

    <tr *ngFor="let list of pipelines">
      <td>{{list.name}}</td>
      <td>{{list.id}}</td>
      <td>{{list.date}}</td>
      <td>{{list.company}}</td>
      <td><button (click)="ExapndCollapse()">Click to Exapand</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td *ngIf="showExapandedRow">Hello There!</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Can you share ur demo code on https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: Actually, I'm doing for my office work. can't share the code. I need to create one dummy one then I will be able to share it through stackblitz.

Comment: Have you taken a look to primeNG? the already have this functionality

Comment: It would be great if u kindly give me any reference link for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

**.html:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>column header1</td>
        <td>column header2</td>
        <td>column header3</td>
        <td>column header4</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let list of pipelines">
        <tr>
            <td>{{list.name}}</td>
            <td>{{list.id}}</td>
            <td>{{list.date}}</td>
            <td>{{list.company}}</td>
            <td><button (click)="ExapndCollapse(list.id)">Click to Exapand</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td [ngClass]="{ 'expandedRow': true, 'active': exapandedRowId === list.id }">Hello There!</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>

</table>
```

**.ts:**

```
  exapandedRowId: number = 0;
  ExapndCollapse(id) {
    this.exapandedRowId = this.exapandedRowId === id? 0 : id;
  }
```

**.css:**

```
.expandedRow {
  display: none;
}
.expandedRow.active {
  display: block;
}
```

I've created a demo with dummy data [**HERE**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k6f1x6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: It won't generate a new instead of that it will add some width to the existing tr whatever tr I clicked.

Comment: Great!! Thanks, Buddy for your effort :) I did solve my problem using            <ng-container>